# LPC810 - why won't machine code execute from an array of uint8_t in flash?

Tags: c, function-pointers, nxp-microcontroller

I'm writing embedded C/assembler code for the NXP LPC810 microcontroller (just a hobby project).

I have a function `fn`.  I also have an *exact* copy of that function's machine code in an array of `uint8_t`.  (I have checked the hex file.)

I create a function pointer `fnptr`, with the same type as `fn` and point it at the array, using a cast.

It all cross-compiles without warnings.

When the MCU executes `fn` it works correctly.

When the MCU executes `fnptr` it crashes (I can't see any debug, as there are only 8 pins, all in use).

The code is position independent.

The array has the correct 4 byte alignment.

`fn` is in the `.text` section of the elf file.

The array is forced into the `.text` section of the elf file (still in flash, not RAM).

I have *assumed* that there is no NX-like functionality on such a basic Coretex M0+ MCU.  (Cortex M3 and M4 do have some form of read-only memory protection for code.)

Are there other reasons why the machine code in the array does not work?

---

Update:

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "serial.h"

extern "C" void SysTick_Handler() {
  // generate an interrupt for delay
}

void delay(int millis) {
    while (--millis >= 0) {
        __WFI(); // wait for SysTick interrupt
    }
}

extern "C" int fn(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

/* arm-none-eabi-objdump -d firmware.elf
00000162 <fn>:
 162:   1840        adds    r0, r0, r1
 164:   4770        bx  lr
 166:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
*/
extern "C" const uint8_t machine_code[6] __attribute__((aligned (4))) __attribute__((section (".text"))) = {
0x40,0x18,
0x70,0x47,
0xc0,0x46
};

int main() {
    LPC_SWM->PINASSIGN0 = 0xFFFFFF04UL;
    serial.init(LPC_USART0, 115200);

    SysTick_Config(12000000/1000); // 1ms ticks
    int(*fnptr)(int a, int b) = (int(*)(int, int))machine_code;

    for (int a = 0; ; a++) {
        int c = fnptr(a, 1000000);
        printf("Hello world2 %d.\n", c);
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

And here is the disassembled output from `arm-none-eabi-objdump -D -Mforce-thumb firmware.elf`:

```
00000162 <fn>:
 162:   1840        adds    r0, r0, r1
 164:   4770        bx  lr
 166:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

00000168 <machine_code>:
 168:   1840        adds    r0, r0, r1
 16a:   4770        bx  lr
 16c:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 16e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

00000170 <main>:
...
```

Comment: Just as a sanity check, could you post the code you use to declare and initialize the function pointer?

Comment: I'll dig out the code tomorrow.

Comment: Anyway, a life without a debugger is tough. You really should look at the `PSP`, `MSP` and friends..

Comment: Are you sure it's position independent code? Unlikely I'd say, which means the code is likely to only run at the linked address, an exact copy is therefore not what you want to see! Disassemble the section, and post the result

Comment: also many embedded systems have a Harvard architecture, meaning that the executable code and the data reside in physically different memory regions. Hence, if you've generated some code, you won't be able to execute it because a function pointer into the data memory isn't meaningful.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant the array is forced into the `.text` section, so even if the LPC810 couldn't execute code from RAM, it wouldn't be an issue.  As you can see, `machine_code` is in the same section as `fn` and `main`.

Comment: @BrianSidebotham code and disassembly provided, but it doesn't work with `fnptr`, using `fn` everything is fine.

Comment: Maybe you want to use some JIT library (e.g. GNU [lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [libjit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libjit.git)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, those are interesting projects of which I was unaware.  Unfortunately I doubt that they are small enough to be useful - the LPC810 which I'm using has 1KB of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I amended the code to call the original `fn` though a function pointer too, in order to be able to generate working and non-working assembly code that was hopefully near-identical.

`machine_code` has become much longer, as I am now using no optimisation (`-O0`).

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "serial.h"

extern "C" void SysTick_Handler() {
  // generate an interrupt for delay
}

void delay(int millis) {
    while (--millis >= 0) {
        __WFI(); // wait for SysTick interrupt
    }
}

extern "C" int fn(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

/*
000002bc <fn>:
 2bc:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
 2be:   b082        sub sp, #8
 2c0:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
 2c2:   6078        str r0, [r7, #4]
 2c4:   6039        str r1, [r7, #0]
 2c6:   687a        ldr r2, [r7, #4]
 2c8:   683b        ldr r3, [r7, #0]
 2ca:   18d3        adds    r3, r2, r3
 2cc:   1c18        adds    r0, r3, #0
 2ce:   46bd        mov sp, r7
 2d0:   b002        add sp, #8
 2d2:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}
*/
extern "C" const uint8_t machine_code[24] __attribute__((aligned (4))) __attribute__((section (".text"))) = {
0x80,0xb5,
0x82,0xb0,
0x00,0xaf,
0x78,0x60,
0x39,0x60,
0x7a,0x68,
0x3b,0x68,
0xd3,0x18,
0x18,0x1c,
0xbd,0x46,
0x02,0xb0,
0x80,0xbd
};

int main() {
    LPC_SWM->PINASSIGN0 = 0xFFFFFF04UL;
    serial.init(LPC_USART0, 115200);

    SysTick_Config(12000000/1000); // 1ms ticks

    int(*fnptr)(int a, int b) = (int(*)(int, int))fn;
    //int(*fnptr)(int a, int b) = (int(*)(int, int))machine_code;

    for (int a = 0; ; a++) {
        int c = fnptr(a, 1000000);
        printf("Hello world2 %d.\n", c);
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

I compiled the code above, generating `firmware.fn.elf` and `firmware.machinecode.elf` by uncommenting `//int(*fnptr)(int a, int b) = (int(*)(int, int))machine_code;` (and commenting-out the line above).

The first code (`fn`) worked, the second code (`machine_code`) crashed.

`fn`'s text and the code at `machine_code` are identical:

```
000002bc <fn>:
 2bc:   b580            push    {r7, lr}
 2be:   b082            sub     sp, #8
 2c0:   af00            add     r7, sp, #0
 2c2:   6078            str     r0, [r7, #4]
 2c4:   6039            str     r1, [r7, #0]
 2c6:   687a            ldr     r2, [r7, #4]
 2c8:   683b            ldr     r3, [r7, #0]
 2ca:   18d3            adds    r3, r2, r3
 2cc:   1c18            adds    r0, r3, #0
 2ce:   46bd            mov     sp, r7
 2d0:   b002            add     sp, #8
 2d2:   bd80            pop     {r7, pc}

000002d4 <machine_code>:
 2d4:   b580            push    {r7, lr}
 2d6:   b082            sub     sp, #8
 2d8:   af00            add     r7, sp, #0
 2da:   6078            str     r0, [r7, #4]
 2dc:   6039            str     r1, [r7, #0]
 2de:   687a            ldr     r2, [r7, #4]
 2e0:   683b            ldr     r3, [r7, #0]
 2e2:   18d3            adds    r3, r2, r3
 2e4:   1c18            adds    r0, r3, #0
 2e6:   46bd            mov     sp, r7
 2e8:   b002            add     sp, #8
 2ea:   bd80            pop     {r7, pc}

000002ec <main>:
...
```

The only difference in the calling code is the location of the code called:

```
$ diff firmware.fn.bin.xxd firmware.machine_code.bin.xxd
54c54
< 0000350: 0040 0640 e02e 0000 bd02 0000 4042 0f00  .@.@........@B..
---
> 0000350: 0040 0640 e02e 0000 d402 0000 4042 0f00  .@.@........@B..
```

The second address `d402` is the address of the `machine_code` array.

Curiously, the first address `bd02` is a little-endian odd number (`d` is odd in hex).

The address of `fn` is `02bc` (`bc02` in big endian), so the pointer to `fn` is *not* the address of `fn`, but the address of `fn` plus one (or with the low bit set).

Changing the code to:

```
...

int main() {
    LPC_SWM->PINASSIGN0 = 0xFFFFFF04UL;
    serial.init(LPC_USART0, 115200);

    SysTick_Config(12000000/1000); // 1ms ticks

    //int(*fnptr)(int a, int b) = (int(*)(int, int))fn;
    int machine_code_addr_low_bit_set = (int)machine_code | 1;
    int(*fnptr)(int a, int b) = (int(*)(int, int))machine_code_addr_low_bit_set;

    for (int a = 0; ; a++) {
        int c = fnptr(a, 1000000);
        printf("Hello world2 %d.\n", c);
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Makes it work.

---

Googling, I found:

The mechanism for switching makes use of the fact that all instructions must be (at least) halfword-aligned, which means that bit[0] of the branch target address is redundant. Therefore this bit can be re-used to indicate the target instruction set at that address. Bit[0] cleared to 0 means ARM and bit[0] set to 1 means Thumb.

on http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka12545.html

---

tl;dr

You need to set the low bit on function pointers when executing data as code on ARM Thumb.